# Error with versions of JDK while creating report using PhpJasper

Tags: java, php, ubuntu, jasper-reports

I trying to create some code with [PHPJasper](https://github.com/PHPJasper/phpjasper), but at same line I get error. I think it's problems with Java SE versions.

File `hello_world.jasper` is already exist in my project.

Source code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPJasper\PHPJasper;

$jasper = new PHPJasper;

$input = __DIR__ . '/vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/examples/hello_world.jasper';
$output = __DIR__ . '/vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/examples';
$options = [
    'format' => ['pdf', 'rtf']
];

$jasper->process(
    $input,
    $output,
    $options
)->execute();

var_dump($jasper);
```

Error in console for  line with `execute()`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at de.cenote.tools.classpath.ApplicationClasspath.add(ApplicationClasspath.java:75)
    at de.cenote.tools.classpath.ApplicationClasspath.add(ApplicationClasspath.java:65)
    at de.cenote.tools.classpath.ApplicationClasspath.addJars(ApplicationClasspath.java:134)
    at de.cenote.tools.classpath.ApplicationClasspath.addJarsRelative(ApplicationClasspath.java:151)
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.processReport(App.java:178)
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.main(App.java:109)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPJasper\Exception\ErrorCommandExecutable: Your report has an error and couldn 't be processed!\ Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console. in /home/jack/PhpstormProjects/JasperTest/vendor/geekcom/phpjasper/src/PHPJasper.php:219
```

Java version:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu219.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu219.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Yeah I would try with version <=8 it's trying to cast as URLClassLoader which works in version 8 or less.

Comment: [Base ClassLoader No Longer from URLClassLoader](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4011800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution of this problem.

I remove all java packages (`sudo apt-get remove openjdk...`) and install again with version Java JDK 1.8 ([instruction for ubuntu](https://www.javahelps.com/2015/03/install-oracle-jdk-in-ubuntu.html))

After this I got correct version of Java:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

And I don't have errors in my project

Comment: I use java version "1.8.0_391" on windows and I have the same error using jasperstarter. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`